# Write changes to script after adding array element

Tags: bash, shell-script

So I have the following script which will show me my bookmarks in dmenu then open the selected Item in firefox.

```
#!/bin/sh

declare -a bookmarks

bookmarks=(
https://www.reddit.com/
https://www.youtube.com/
https://github.com/
https://www.veganricha.com/
)

input="$2"
addnew() {
    bookmarks+=("$input")
}


while getopts a: option; do
    case "${option}" in
        a) addnew && exit 0 ;;
    esac
done

menu="dmenu -i -l 10 -p "Bookmarks""
items=$(printf '%s\n' "${bookmarks[@]}" | $menu )

[ -n "$items" ] && firefox $items || exit 0
```

when you run it with the -a flag, you can add an Item to the list (the last copied item in my case)

```
./bookmarks -a $(xclicp -o)
```

and it does indeed add the item. what I want is to write the changes to the script. so the newly added item using `-a` flag be written to the script.

I tried and searched a lot but couldn't figure it out, hope someone can help

Thank you in advance

Comment: I think the best is to put the bookmarks elements in a separate file, as they are data. Then the script reads that file into the bookmarks array and appends new entries to the file.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of modifying the script itself it will probably be better to have the bookmarks in a separate file and modify that file instead like [Quasimodo commented](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/584391/write-changes-to-script-after-adding-array-element#comment1088194_584391)

You can do this by modifying the script to something like the following:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

bookmark_file=~/bookmark_list

declare -a bookmarks

bookmarks=($(<$bookmark_file))

input="$2"
addnew() {
    echo $input >> $bookmark_file
}


while getopts a: option; do
    case "${option}" in
        a) addnew && exit 0 ;;
    esac
done

menu="dmenu -i -l 10 -p "Bookmarks""
items=$(printf '%s\n' "${bookmarks[@]}" | $menu )

[ -n "$items" ] && firefox $items || exit 0
```

And have the bookmarks in a file at `~/bookmark_list`, the file storing the bookmarks can be easily changed by changing the `bookmark_file` variable

Comment: while this answer is correct, and that's why I gave you an upvote, I can't mark it as accepted because it doesn't answer the question itself.